# In MySql GROUP BY and SUM() in same Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to sum the total seconds like answer is total_seconds 49058 and billable is 540 it group by billable, I already try the below mentioned mysql query.

```
ID   billable total_seconds
----------------------------
9326      480          2254
9352       60          3657
9352       60          2756
9352       60            14
9326      480          2607
9326      480           122
9326      480           162
9326      480           559
9326      480          2478
9326      480           313
9326      480           234
9326      480           548
9326      480          2400
9326      480           564
9326      480          4449
9326      480         12986
9326      480         12942
9326      480            13
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    sub.user_id,
    e.name, e.employee_id,
    sub.id, sub.billable,
    history.total_seconds
FROM 
    v_wa_tasks as t
JOIN 
    v_wa_sub_tasks as sub ON t.id = sub.task_id 
JOIN 
    v_wa_task_histories as history ON sub.id = history.sub_task_id
JOIN 
    v_employees as e ON sub.user_id = e.id  
WHERE 
    e.id = 18 
    AND t.status_id = 5 
    AND t.status_id != 9 
    AND t.task_nature_id != 4  
    AND sub.review_type = 0 
    AND t.start_time BETWEEN "2017-10-05 00:00:00" AND "2017-10-05 23:59:00"
```

Comment: hint: using distinct inside your select. select sum(distinct billable) from your_table.

Comment: if the valid billable data is 8hrs+8 hrs+8hrs then `sum(distinct billable)` = 8hrs = Wrong! Not good advice imho @FahadAnjum

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which is liable to prove problematic in due course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select distinct` and `sum` rarely work well together. Almost always you need to do more work as subqueries to not only get the correct sum, but to reduce the rows as well. Here is a possible way to sum the history:

```
SELECT
      sub.user_id
    , e.NAME
    , e.employee_id
    , sub.id
    , sub.billable
    , history.total_seconds
FROM v_wa_tasks AS t
INNER JOIN v_wa_sub_tasks AS sub ON t.id = sub.task_id
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
            sub_task_id
          , SUM(total_seconds) total_seconds
      FROM v_wa_task_histories
      GROUP BY
            sub_task_id
) AS history ON sub.id = history.sub_task_id
INNER JOIN v_employees AS e ON sub.user_id = e.id
WHERE e.id = 18
AND t.status_id = 5
AND t.status_id != 9
AND t.task_nature_id != 4
AND sub.review_type = 0
AND t.start_time >= '2017-10-05' AND t.start_time < '2017-10-06'
```

**NB**: '23:59:59' is **NOT** the end of a day, and using that could get you into trouble one day (MySQL now does support sub-second time precision). The best solution is to AVOID "between" in date ranges. Use `>=` and `<` instead, but note that you "push up" the higher date to the next day. See [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)